# CSS "position: fixed;" layout inconsistency in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Bear with me, as this requires a bit of explanation...

**History**: In order to create a fixed-width, 2-column layout with the right column fixed to the top of the window, I use the following general approach (this is conceptual code, not real).

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap { width: 1000px; }
.left { width: 700px; display: inline-block; }
.right {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: auto; }
```

**The Problem**: I have a site using this approach where the right container intermittently renders on top of the left container, instead of to the right of it as expected.  This only happens in Chrome, and you may have to refresh the page a few times to see the problem.

[Here's a link to the site](http://kristynfishleighphotography.com/category/london-ontario-photography-blog/)

**The Catch**: I know that there are hundred things going on with that page, and that the "right: auto;" rule is dependent upon where the element would be positioned statically.  However, if you inspect the right container in the dev tools (#sidebar in the DOM) and change it's CSS position from fixed to static, it jumps to the expected layout position.  Then if you change it back to fixed, it stays there.  That seems weird (buggy) to me.

**The Bottom Line**: It seems to me that Chrome is occasionally calculating the layout incorrectly when the page initially is drawn. I don’t know much about what order browsers handle calculations in when drawing a page, and am stumped as to why this would be happening or how to even begin debugging this issue.  I'm hoping the particular circumstances would give someone who knows more about these things a clue as to where I could start looking.

Comment: Why does "#inner-wrap" display is set to "inline-block" ? why not just leave it as a block level element and use right:0 with absolute position on "#sidebar" ?

Comment: just done several refreshes on Chrome, and it works fine!

Comment: @elad.chen The #sidebar element needs to be "position: fixed" so it doesn't scroll with the rest of the page.  "right: 0" on a fixed element would put it flush with the right of the window, not flush with the right of "#middle-wrap" where I want it.

Comment: I do not think it should work.. "The CSS specification requires that position:fixed be anchored to the viewport, not the containing positioned element."

Comment: @elad.chen "position: fixed" plus "right: auto" anchors the element where it would be positioned if it were "position: static".  It's a bit magical, but it works (usually) :)

Comment: Weird problem. For me it's only manifesting itself on the initial load, and not any of the reloads. You have right click disabled, so troubleshooting your problem is a lot harder. You should change that while asking for help.

Comment: Check out my answer, It might not be the answer you are looking for; but it does include the "correct" way to achieve the desired layout.

Comment: @elan.chen That is another good alternative approach.  Really, I like my original approach the best (yes, I'm biased), because I think it's cleaner and simpler and it **should** work.  The main answer I'm looking for is why it isn't working consistently in Chrome.  I do appreciate the answer though and may end up using it if I can't solve the other :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why your initial bug happens, but as I see you have fixed width for `#inner-wrap` so get rid of `display:inline-block` on the `#sidebar` and instead of `padding-left:75px` on it do `margin-left:630px`.
This should look exactly the same in all browsers.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50n9bn5q/1/)

Comment: This is a good alternate approach.  Thanks.  I'm going to hold off on accepting this answer though because I'm most interested in why the initial approach isn't working consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I took a few minutes to create a proper layout for you.

I can't tell why this works in the first place, like I'v said in my comment:

> The CSS specification requires that position:fixed be anchored to the viewport, not the containing positioned element.

Anyway here's what I came up with:

CSS:

```
/* In case a css reset is not used */
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { margin: 0 }

.container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: red;
}

#header {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 180px; // Can be removed if should be automatically set
}

#header, #content {
    width: 555px;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}

#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 800px;
    top: 0;
}

#sidebar-content {
    float: right;
    width: 245px;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 900px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="header">
        <!-- img tag goes here -->
    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="sidebar-content">Test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7repkwq/1/)